# how to use jQuery.add()?

Tags: jquery

I just can not get, what the function [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) is used for.

As I read documentation, for instance, a piece of code

```
<p>Hello</p>
<span>Hello Again</span>

$( "p" ).add( "span" ).css( "background", "yellow" );
```

can be done easier,  like this, does not it?

```
$( "p, span" ).css( "background", "yellow" );
```

Comment: jQuery has a API site where all functions are described with examples. For you case see: http://api.jquery.com/add/

Comment: And he linked exactly to that in his first sentence ;)

Comment: Too quick reading :-) Thanks Martijn

Comment: .add is helpful in many cases. I often you it when combining elements or element collections. I made a simple example for you http://jsfiddle.net/X7RQW/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi jquery add() fucnction actullay performs Adding elements to the set of matched elements.

Like in ur case..

```
$( "p" ).add( "span" ).css( "background", "yellow" );
```

adding span to all p elements with span backround as yellow.. i have also added a fiddle for the same to explain.http://jsbin.com/ENufeNu/1/edit

Comment: my removed answer stated the same, but if you read the documentation again it says it adds to the selection, not the dom :)

Comment: @Luceos my fiddle shows that style gets added to all P elements in DOM check out.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does that. However, the add function has some more options, like adding html
From their docs:

```
$( "li" ).add( "<p id='new'>new paragraph</p>" )
    .css( "background-color", "red" );
```

Your `$( "p, span" )` example is very basic, this add allows for a lot more complicated options.

Another example of a different usage is the chain:

```
$('p:first-child').css({color: 'green'}).add('p').css({background: 'blue'})
```

All P's will have a blue BG, but only the first one will have a green order

Comment: The first example that you found from jQuery docs is pretty weird, it does not actually add the p to the dom as it states on the docs also "Although the new paragraph has been created and its background color changed, it still does not appear on the page. To place it on the page, we could add one of the insertion methods to the chain."